# Iterate through elements in html tree using BeautifulSoup, and produce an output that maintains the relative position of each element? in Python

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jsoup

I have this code that does what I need it to do using Jsoup in Java

```
Elements htmlTree = doc.body().select("*");

    Elements menuElements = new Elements();

    for(Element element : htmlTree) {

        if(element.hasClass("header")) 
            menuElements.add(element);
        if(element.hasClass("name"))
            menuElements.add(element);
        if(element.hasClass("quantity"))
            menuElements.add(element);
    }
```

I want to do the same thing but in Python using BeautifulSoup. An example tree of the HTML I'm trying to scrape follows:

```
<div class="header"> content </div>
     <div class="name"> content </div>
     <div class="quantity"> content </div>
     <div class="name"> content </div>
     <div class="quantity"> content </div>
<div class="header"> content2 </div>
     <div class="name"> content2 </div>
     <div class="quantity"> content2 </div>
     <div class="name"> content2 </div>
     <div class="quantity"> content2 </div>
```

etc.

Basically I want the output to preserve the relative positions of each element. How would I got about doing that using Python and BeautifulSoup?

EDIT:

This is the python code I have (it's very naive) but maybe it can help?

```
output = []

for e in soup :
  if e["class"] == "pickmenucolmenucat" :
    output.append(e)
  if e["class"] == "pickmenucoldispname" :
    output.append(e)
  if e["class"] == "pickmenucolportions" :
    output.append(e)
```

Comment: what made you think that BeautifulSoup doesn't preserve order? Show the code that you have.

Comment: I don't really have anything. The problem I'm having is that there's some empty and useless tags in my content. What I did with jSoup was basically go down and check every tag if they had the class I needed then adding the element to a list if it matched. I want to know how to do this in, or if theres an easier way to do it

Comment: I added an edit with my python code (very naive) it also gives me a type error (string indices must be integers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find all `<div>` elements that have `class` attribute from a given list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

with open('input.xml', 'rb') as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file)

elements = soup.find_all("div", class_="header name quantity".split())
print("\n".join("{} {}".format(el['class'], el.get_text()) for el in elements))
```

#### Output

```
['header']  content 
['name']  content 
['quantity']  content 
['name']  content 
['quantity']  content 
['header']  content2 
['name']  content2 
['quantity']  content2 
['name']  content2 
['quantity']  content2
```

There are also [other methods that allows you to search, traverse html elements](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree).